# Which Chromium version has H.264 support?

Tags: chromium

The [German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_(Browser)) says for Chromimum:

```
"Since March 2019 there are versions of the Chromium Project that include all codecs: H.264 and AAC, and even H.265"
```

The English Wikipedia however doesn't mention this.

Not being too familiar with Wikipedia, I find a bit strange that something is mentioned on a certain language version of Wikipedia.

I would however like to ask which version exactely they talk about on the German Wikipedia.

How could I find out which version they talk about exactely?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chromium builds by default do not include support for "proprietary codecs" that require patent licensing.

If you build from source, you can enable them using these flags:

```
proprietary_codecs=true ffmpeg_branding=Chrome
```

For building Chromium from source as part of the build process for the Chromium Embedded Framework, see the CEF build notes:

https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/BranchesAndBuilding

You can build from source with proprietary codecs support using Chromium source versions going back to at least 2015, probably much longer.

Note that building from source requires a decent-spec'd machine: 16 GB or more of RAM, 80+ GB of disk space.